# Convert from int array to char array

Tags: c++, c, gcc

After searching around I couldn't understand how to convert a value obtained from an int array [x] to char array [x]
Executing this code gives me a null result.

I saw syntax like `char x = 98;`

Its work with single var but doesnt work with array.

```
#include  <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int st[6]={99,102,107,111,117,121};
    int cl = 0;
    char pw[7]={'\0'};

    for (cl = 0; cl > 7; cl++){
        if (cl == 1){ pw[1] =  st[2];}
        if (cl == 2){ pw[2] =  st[5];}
        if (cl == 3){ pw[3] =  st[1];}
        if (cl == 4){ pw[4] =  st[3];}
        if (cl == 5){ pw[5] =  st[6];}
        if (cl == 6){ pw[6] =  st[4];}
        if (cl == 7){ pw[7] =  st[5];}
    }               
     printf("\n : %c ", pw);                
    return 0;
}
```

I need the code to encrypt text and then decipher them.
I'd like to know where I'm wrong.
PS: If you run the code I don't take responsibility for the result.

Comment: Please extract and provide a [mcve]. Also, please describe what you observed and what you expected to see instead, not just your interpretation thereof.

Comment: Unrelated, but arrays in C and C++ are 0 based, not 1 based.

Comment: This site uses a Question and Answer format, please do not edit the question to contain the answer. Instead you can accept a posted answer, or post your own answer in the Answer box

Comment: @M.M Good to know for next time thank you for advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Useless use of for loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop-switch_sequence)<sup>1</sup>....

Actually it's worse than useless, because the iteration condition (`cl > 7`) is always false and the loop never runs.

Remove the for loop.

Then, fix the printf format string.  You can't pair a pointer with `%c`.  You also can't use `%s` because that is for NUL-terminated strings.

---

<sup>1</sup> [The citations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop-switch_sequence#cite_note-2) are particularly illuminating.